# Jenkins Master Slave Interaction

Tags: jenkins

Does the Server maintain a constant/continuous connection with client throughout the build process? or is the interaction between server and client connectionless?

As in does it open a connection distribute builds, close connection, And after the build is over client opens a connection to the master and reports?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A connection is maintained between the master and slave, if just so the console output can be displayed on the master real time (and perhaps other status reporting as well).

Apart from that, builds (i.e., the process executing the build) is self contained and executes independently on the slave machines.